# Existence of unique circle passing through interior points of unit disk meeting the boundary orthogonally

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

I am a self-studies and this is a hw problem from a complex analysis scourse I've been doing.

The problem set pertains to the topic Automorphism Groups and has a high concentration of fractional linear transformations. So I would be appreciative of any help, but especially if those concepts are applicable.

> > Show that for any points $a, b\in D$, the unit disk, there is a unique circle $C$ passing through $a$ and $b$ and meeting $\partial D$ orthogonally. (Suggestion: Prove first that the only circles through $0$ and perpendicular to $\partial D$ are diameters of D.)

As far as the hint goes, it makes sense that radii are perpendicular to tangents to the circle, so if the radii lie on a line, it is a diameter. But this doesn't seem like much of a proof.

Also as far as the general case, I can see how a circle through $a$ and $b$ and centered outside of $D$ can have orthogonal intersections with the $\partial D$ and how the respective right triangles formed by $0$ and the two tangents to the circle from the center of $C$ work.

But I would appreciate help proving the existence and uniqueness. Especially if there is a way using fractional linear transformations.

Thanks

Comment: You know that linear fractional transformations take (lines and) circles to (lines and) circles, and that they preserve angles, right? Hence if $\phi$ is an automorphism of the disk solving the problem for $a$ and $b$ is equivalent to solving it for $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$. Hence you can assume $a=0$. At which point the hint becomes useful. ("doesn't seem like much of a proof": Well, as far as what you posted here goes, you haven't _given_ a proof for the hint...)

Comment: Think about it some more! At this point we're done if we show that the $x$-axis is the only line or circle passing through $0$ and $1$ and meeting the unit circle at right angles. A circle passing through $0$ and $1$ must have its center on the line $x=1/2$... what does that look like?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich the $x$-axis between $0$ and $1$ looks like the diameter of the circle centered at $x=1/2$ and the radius of the unit circle. So it would be perpendicular to the inner circle and the unit circle at $x=1$. Does that constitute a proof of the hint?

Comment: Well no. You need to show this: If a circle passes through $0$ and $1$ and meets the unit circle at right angles then it must actually be the $x-axis$. So suppose you have such a circle that's not a line. Where must its center be? So  what?

Comment: @DavidC.Ulrich Dear Professor - Please forgive me for being so incredibly dense. I can't think of another circle that goes through $0$ and $1$ that meets the unit circle at right angles. The circle centered at $x=1/2$ above that meets these criteria would have its center at $i\infty$? I truly apologize for my lack of insight.

Comment: That's the point! You have to _show_ that there is no such circle.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for your patience. I'm working on applying this to the problem itself. I am guessing I need to come up with the appropriate diameter of the unit circle applicable to the given pair $a,b$ and the circle it determines. Maybe map the chord to a parallel diameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

different problems may be easiest in different models. This one is best in the upper half plane. You need to know that any Mobius transformation preserves angles (including right angles) and maps any line or circle into either a line or circle.

To take the unit disc to the upper half plane, use
$$  f(z) = \frac{z + i}{iz+1}. $$

To take the upper half plane to the disc, use
$$  g(z) = \frac{iz + 1}{z+i}. $$
Which, now that I look at them together, are just reciprocals.

In the upper half plane, given two distinct points, there are just two possibilities. If two points are on a vertical ray, because both have the same real part, that is the line through them. If the two points have different real parts, draw the ordinary line segment between them, draw the perpendicular bisector of that segment, it meets the real axis at a point, call it $P.$ The semicircle with center at $P$ that passes through both original points is what you want.

In both cases, the curve described is mapped to the unit disc to either a diameter or a circular arc that is orthogonal to the boundary. It is worth the exercise to find out what happens to $z = A + i e^t$ under the mapping $  g(z) = \frac{iz + 1}{z+i}. $ Here $A$ is real constant, $t$ the real variable.

Comment: Dear Will - Thank you for your guidance. As you can see above, I am struggling with the kind help I am receiving from Prof. Ulrich. Even if I get no further, maybe you would please elaborate a bit as to why the upper half plane would be advantageous. Regards,

Comment: @Andrew, done. I have attempted to stick with formulas. There are a number of pictures in this area, it is difficult to get across visual information online. It is different in a classroom or tutoring one person at a time, in person.

Comment: Thanks very much. I am busy working things out. It looks very convenient , as you say.